# Laravel 5.6 - eager load depending on value in parent table

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many, eager-loading

Post.php

```
$fillable = ['id','flag'];

public function tags() 
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tags')->withPivot('pivot_flag');
}

public function flaggedTags()
{
  return $this->tags()->where('pivot_flag', 1)->get();
}
```

Tag.php

```
$fillable = ['id']
public function posts() 
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}
```

Pivot table `post_tag` columns: `post_id`,`tag_id`,`pivot_flag`

I need to fetch Post with Tags:

```
$post = Post::select('id','flag')->with('tags')->find($postId);
```

However, if the `flag` is set to `1` in Post then I only want tags which have `pivot_flag` value in pivot table `post_tag` set to `1`

So in that case I'd have following:

```
$post = Post::select('id','flag')->with('flaggedTags')->find($postId);
```

How can I do this in single query? I could always do one query to check if the `Post` is flagged or not and then run the appropriate query for `Tags`, but that seems wasteful.

Eloquent or raw MySQL queries are welcome.

Thanks!

UPDATE - Alternative solution

Load all tags and then filter the result depending on Post's `flag` value:

```
if($post->flag)
{
  $tags = $post->tags->filter(funtction($q) {
     return $q->pivot->pivot_flag == 1;
  });
}
else 
{
  $tags = $post->tags;
}
```

This might be faster depending on number of `tags`. Not really sure, need to test it though. Any feedback about this in comments is welcome.

Comment: This will always require two queries.

Comment: Thanks @JonasStaudenmeir Can you point me to some further reading on MySQL?

Comment: I hoped you maybe had a link for a specific explanation why this can't be achieved with MySQL. Don't worry about it.

Comment: That's a general limitation and not specific to MySQL. You can improve the performance by filtering the query (instead of the results): `$post->tags()->where('pivot_flag', 1)->get()`

Comment: Yes, that was the idea behind `flaggedTags()` but somehow I typed out something else. Updated.